# after click on submit button record will added to the table, so how to verify that record is added or not in the table

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng, dynamic-testing

*There is add employee form, so how to verify the record, should I match the all fields of form which display on table or just match the name, also table is dynamic  with pagination.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several ways depending on which features your table provides:

1. **There is search functionality in your table.** You can add a user and then look up the required record using search.
2. **There is sort feature in your table.** You add a user considering sorting so that your user would go to table top entry. Then you invoke sorting and check if the top entry represents your user
3. **There is pagination and you know how many pages are there.** You go page by page unless you encounter your required entry. If the pages are over and you have not encountered your entry, test fails.
4. **There is pagination and you do not know know how many pages are there.** Bad news. Ask your devs for advice.

Regarding the fields to check, **you should match all the fields** which are provided by your table against the values you have input in the form, otherwise you can miss some issues like:

- the values are saved by the server but improperly requested by front-end
- the values are not saved by the server
- front end didn't pass values to the server
- front-end passed values to the server but confused field-to-value assignement
- front-end confused the order of returned values when populated the table.